# Proof of the error function being holomorphic and independent of path

Tags: complex-analysis, error-function

I have been searching around and can't seem to find any answer to the following two questions anywhere and it has started to become really frustrating!

1. Prove that the error function is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$
2. Prove that the error function is independent of the path between the boundaries of the integral (How can I formulate this question better?)

For reference erf(z) = $\operatorname{erf} z = \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^z e^{-t^2}\,dt.$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it as simple as noting that $\operatorname{erf}$ is differentiable by FTC (since $\operatorname{erf}'(z) = e^{-z^2}$)?

Comment: (2) is just Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Any analytic function on a simply-connected domain has an analytic antiderivative on that domain.

Comment: Is there a particular proof method you want to use? Both statements follow immediately from well-known theorems of complex analysis.

Comment: I think it would suffice to just state those theorems so I can look them up!